# Java меню в стиле Microsoft Office 2007

Tags: java

Добрый день. Ни кто не делал меню в стиле Microsoft Office 2007 - где под большой кнопкой прячутся основные менюшки. И еще такую кнопку сделали в firefox. Как на java+swing такое реализовать, может уже есть готовые компоненты )

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я пользуюсь primefaces, есть такая [штука](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/stack.jsf).

Остальное можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf), посмотрите блок "Menu"

Comment: Штука хорошая, но для Веба. Вопрос свой некоректно составил, пишу дестктопное приложение swing